# Couldn't find the expected Java Key Stores (JKS) files! They are mandatory when encryption via TLS is enabled with Kafka Bitnami helm chart

Tags: ssl, apache-kafka, bitnami

I'm deploying the kafka bitnami chart with TLS enabled for the external client for testing.

I follow the instruction, however, I've got following error. What is wrong with my configuration?

```
$ kubectl logs my-release-kafka-0
Couldn't find the expected Java Key Stores (JKS) files! They are mandatory when encryption via TLS is enabled.
```

Secret Creation is like this.

```
kubectl create secret generic kafka-jks --from-file=./kafka.truststore.jks --from-file=./kafka-0.keystore.jks
```

Deploy helm chart is following.

```
helm install my-release \
  --set externalAccess.enabled=true \
  --set externalAccess.service.type=LoadBalancer \
  --set externalAccess.service.port=9094 \
  --set externalAccess.autoDiscovery.enabled=true \
  --set serviceAccount.create=true \
  --set rbac.create=true \
  --set auth.clientProtocol=tls \
  --set auth.jksSecret=kafka-jks \
  --set auth.jksPassword=<MY_JKS_PASSWORD> \
bitnami/kafka
```

According to the kubectl describe pod, it looks successfully mounted.

```
    Mounts:
      /bitnami/kafka from data (rw)
      /certs from kafka-certificates (ro)
      /opt/bitnami/kafka/logs from logs (rw)
      /scripts/setup.sh from scripts (rw,path="setup.sh")
      /shared from shared (rw)
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from my-release-kafka-token-bkqgt (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True 
  Ready             False 
  ContainersReady   False 
  PodScheduled      True 
Volumes:
  data:
    Type:       PersistentVolumeClaim (a reference to a PersistentVolumeClaim in the same namespace)
    ClaimName:  data-my-release-kafka-0
    ReadOnly:   false
  scripts:
    Type:      ConfigMap (a volume populated by a ConfigMap)
    Name:      my-release-kafka-scripts
    Optional:  false
  shared:
    Type:       EmptyDir (a temporary directory that shares a pod's lifetime)
    Medium:     
    SizeLimit:  <unset>
  kafka-certificates:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  kafka-jks
    Optional:    false
             :
```

```
$ kubectl describe secret kafka-jks
Name:         kafka-jks
Namespace:    default
Labels:       <none>
Annotations:  <none>

Type:  Opaque

Data
====
kafka-0.keystore.jks:  5181 bytes
kafka.truststore.jks:  1346 bytes
```

I also test if the keystore works correctly. It looks work.

```
$ keytool -keystore kafka-0.keystore.jks -export -alias localhost -rfc -file signed_exported.crt
Enter keystore password:  
Certificate stored in file <signed_exported.crt>
```

Comment: Could not reproduce this unfortunately. You can try to deploy with --set 'command[0]=sleep,args[0]=infinity' then exec into the pod and check that the certs directory is properly mounted. The you can then try to run the `/scripts/setup.sh` script and see what happens, if it fails you will be in the containerized environment and be able to debug more.

Comment: @sandyuu Have you been able to find the solution? I've run into the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

There are inconsistencies in the README page of the github repo. The parameters `auth.jksSecret` and `auth.jksPassword` are deprecated, now that JKS and PEM are supported.
Here are the parameters to use instead:

```
helm install my-release \
...
--set=auth.tls.existingSecret=kafka-jks \
--set=auth.tls.password=<MY_JKS_PASSWORD> \
...
bitnami/kafka
```